# undefined method `encode' for ActiveSupport::JSON:Module

Tags: ruby, json, activesupport

I am getting this error pretty regularly, but it also seems to be pretty randomly.

```
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:20:in `to_json'
```

This is occurring sporadically when calling to_json on a hash, for example:

```
{:@i=>18}.to_json
```

Anyone run across this before?  It's strange and can't find much on the internets related.

Answer (score 4):

I get this when using threads (but I'm not using activerecord but SimpleRecord (amazon's db). Solution is to use .to_json first without threads:

```
MyFantasticModel.first.to_json 
# and then run the threaded stuff
@threads << Thread.new {...
```

Comment: So do you think this is SimpleRecord (or perhaps 'aws' gem) related?

Comment: I think it's activesupport initialization related. I've switched the backend on my simplerecord to fog to run on european servers.

Comment: Should be an activerecord thing, yeah. I have the same issue coming up every now and then. A initializer like this `{:a => :b}.to_s` as the first line of the program helped me fix it.

Comment: This also fixes it when I uses threads. I think it's because ActiveRecord lazily initializes the to_json function. If it ends up doing this within a thread, then your other threads might try accessing it before it's properly initialized.